# Ideal voltage vs ideal current source - which one wins?

Tags: current-source, voltage-source, ideal

Here is an example 5.8 from Hayt "Engineering Circuit Analysis" - 8th edition (p.146).

[image: Ex 5.8]

The goal is to find Thevenin equivalent faced by 1k\$\Omega\$ resistor. I am  trying to solve it using the suggested procedure. In particular, I disconnected 1k\$\Omega\$ resistor and now I am trying to determine voltage drop across 2 mA current source. So I am facing the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAfYXB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It is not too difficult to solve it using superposition principle, but my main question now is as follows. We have ideal voltage source facing ideal current source. This is contradictory. If ideal current source is to provide 2 mA current then voltage source would not be able to build enough potential difference and vice versa. Ideal voltage source should be able to provide enough potential difference to prevent ideal current source from working. Is my question valid? What are the assumptions to make it work? Is the physics model for it?

P.S. I checked with multisim.com (online circuit simulator) and Circuitlab.com they both provide correct answers.

Comment: No war here. The current source will force the current direction. Thus, the ideal voltage source will absorb power,  it will be charged by a current source just like a battery in your phone.

Comment: @G36 so the rule is that current source wins. How is it different from missing 4v source (short circuit)

Comment: The point is that by adding the series resistor you have removed the "ideality" of the voltage source, and the combination of the voltage source + series resistor can be seen as a model of  a non-ideal volatge source.

Comment: When you remove the voltage source the voltage drop across the current source will be 4V. On the other hand with the voltage source present in a circuit, now the voltage drop across the current source will be 8V.

Comment: @user1700890 The rule is not that the current source wins, it's that both sources win. The current source makes 2 mA flow through R1, generating 4 V across it. The voltage source forces 4 V at the left end of R1. So we end up with 8 V at the right end of R1. There's 2 mA flowing into the voltage source, so it's absorbing power, as if it's a 4 V battery being charged, or maybe just a shunt 4 V regulator. A common trick when using simulators to measure a current in a wire is to place a 0 V voltage source in series with it, and measure the current through that.

Comment: @user1700890 please read what you wrote in the title

Comment: There seems to common opinion that voltage source would absorb power (as if being charged). Why would not current source absorb power (as if being charged)?

Comment: @user1700890 You can see it as if current source is "absorbing voltage". In your circuit the voltage drop on the resistor would be 4V in the same polarity as the voltage source, so the total voltage in the loop is `4V+4V+V_current_source` which is per KCL is supposed to be zero. So your current source is "absorbing" `8V` which are dropping in it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you! Does 4V drop over resistor come from 2mA current source? (2mA * 2 Om). I do not think we can use this argument. We do not know neither current no voltage in the circuit. My question is about circuit being not well define.

Comment: We know everything. The current source is forcing the current, there is no contradiction. The current is setting the voltage drop on the resistor. The voltage source is forcing the voltage between the ground and the left part of the resistor. This circuit is perfectly "physical" and well defined.

Comment: @EugeneSh., Good point, I am actually concerned about physics of this circuit. It would be great to see how it is possible to have both voltage difference and current in different directions (as they are stated) on electron movement level.

Comment: @user1700890 Noooooooo! If you're doing circuit theory, please ignore electrons. They only serve to confuse. If you're doing electrolysis, semiconductor physics, plasma physics, fine, deal with electrons. But not for circuit theory, conventional current is all you need. If you make V1 deliver (say) -10 V, then you'll find it's sourcing power into both the resistor and the current source. Voltage and current source connected together is one of the best defined circuits to analyse, as we know both current and voltage, regardless of anything else in the circuit.

Answer (score 8):

> Ideal voltage vs ideal current source - which one wins?

An ideal voltage source has zero output impedance. An ideal current source has infinite impedance. So, if you connect both in parallel, they do their jobs *independently*:

- the voltage source sets the voltage across the current source,
- the current source sets the current through the voltage source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnYwI1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is some source of confusion, since you may be used to resistors, where the current and voltage are bound by Ohm's law. But that doesn't mean that in every circuit the voltage and current must be related by Ohm's law - that's only true in isolation for each resistor. You may well have a circuit with no resistors, or with other active components that make it behave differently.

> We have ideal voltage source facing ideal current source. This is contradictory.

It is not.

> If ideal current source is to provide 2mA current then voltage source would not be able to build enough potential difference and vice versa.

A voltage source is an idealized component. It is "able" to build the potential difference always, by definition, no matter how big or small the load current is. In practical terms, imagine a big honking power supply that turns into a welder when the output is shorted.

But in this case, for a 2mA load, even a 45-year-old IC op-amp will do just fine as an ideal voltage source.

Conceptually, a voltage source is a special case of a short circuit with non-zero voltage across it. Other than that, it is a short circuit. So you can arrive at your circuit as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHDw8I.png)</sup>

First, we replace the short from R1 to ground with a 0V voltage source. Nothing changes. Then we change the voltage on it. Again, not much changes, since the current source is an infinite impedance. The voltage and current across R1 are the same in all three circuits!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frHcW5.png)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but more of a suggestion to lead you there:

- The voltage dropped across the ideal voltage source is fixed (no matter what the rest of the circuit is doing).
- The current through out the whole loop is fixed by the current source (no matter what the voltage drops are of each element). This includes every component in the loop.
- The voltage dropped across the resistor is fixed (indirectly) because the current through it is fixed by the previous argument.

Given those constraints, the voltage dropped across the current source is the only property free to change in order for the sum of voltage drops and sources to equal net zero (see KVL).

Note: Current can flow in the reverse polarity of a voltage source. This is counter-intuitive because 99% of the time we consider voltage sources as power sources. The implication is now the voltage source becomes a load. In that same vein, the corollary could be made for the current source. (-V x A = -W = V x -A)

Comment: Thank you! The last note is similar to comments where voltage absorbs power (as if it is charged). Why would not current source absorb power (as if it is charged) and reverse direction of the flow. If reversal of polarity is possible in voltage source, so should the current direction change in current source.

Comment: @user1700890 Right. Charging a battery is the epitome of current going the "wrong" way. But you are missing the point of the ideal current source - it keeps the magnitude and direction fixed NO MATTER WHAT the rest of the circuit is doing - It holds the proverbial current fort down in its loop. In this case, the whole, and only, loop. The ideal current source CAN absorb power if the VOLTAGE polarity across it is negative, but its current can't be reversed by any elements and sources - that breaks the laws of electrical engineering. More specifically, the definition of "ideal current source".

Comment: Thank you, could you share source for definition of ideal current and voltage source?

Comment: @user1700890, you can make your current source absorb power by connecting it to a voltage source with the negative voltage terminal on the "outgoing" current terminal and vice versa.

Comment: @user1700890 *could you share source for definition of ideal current and voltage source* As used in EE textbooks, voltage and current sources are assumed ideal unless specified otherwise.

Comment: @user1700890: An idea current source is a component where the current through it is a fixed constant.  This implies that the voltage across it is whatever it takes to make that happen, either positive, negative, or zero in a short circuit (like a superconductor or ideal wire).  An idea voltage source is one where the voltage is fixed.  Current is arbitrary, again either positive or negative, with no implication that the output power (V * I) needs to be positive.

Comment: @user1700890: So an ideal current source can actually work as a current *limiter* if current would have been higher if it was replaced with a wire.  (e.g. in series with a real battery or ideal voltage source, with opposite polarity to your circuit.)

Answer (score 2):

Let's examine the properties of the sources:

- ***Voltage source***: It will not oppose any current through it, in either direction, but its nature is to impose a fixed potential difference, of fixed polarity, regardless of direction or magnitude of current that flows through it.
- ***Current source***: You are free to impose any potential difference you like across it, in either polarity, but it will decide the current that flows, and in which direction, regardless of the polarity and magnitude of voltage across it.

By those definitions, neither is incompatible with the other, even if they are connected directly in parallel:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4ppU6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The current source is only in charge of current, the voltage source is only in charge of voltage, and there's no contradiction at all.

By placing a resistor in the path, we don't introduce a contradiction either:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQx3Ep.png)</sup>

There's still 2mA flowing in the loop, and there's still 4V across the voltage source. Nobody "wins" because there's no contest.

The only thing that's changed here is that the resistor develops 4V due to the 2mA through it (Ohm's law). The sum of voltages across V1 and R1 is now +8V, which appears across source I1 in accordance with KVL.

If there's still some confusion, perhaps it would help to consider the current source's behaviour in these terms: a current source will develop whatever potential difference is necessary in order to achieve its specified current and direction. In your case, it wouldn't be wrong to say that the current source is producing a potential difference of 8V in order to push 2mA through the resistor, but it's a *little* naive, as I'll explain now.

Just a little extra perspective to mull over:

Perhaps it seems like a bit of a "chicken and egg" thing. Most people understand that current flows through something as a result of a potential difference across it, but in the case of the current source it seems that a voltage is being caused by the current flowing. So which is it?

It's neither. When you apply Ohm's law, KVL and KCL, what you have is a set of simultaneous equations that describe the instantaneous state of the whole system, and the idea of cause and effect has no role to play. You must accept that the system achieves an equilibrium in which the measurable quantities we call voltage, current and resistance at any point in the system are a consequence of all elements of the whole system simultaneously.

From that perspective, voltage, current and resistance are three aspects of the same underlying principle, electricity. In fact even the term "simultaneous equations" suggests that the state of the system is determined without regard to what causes what.

---

The physics of a voltage source are such that charges at one end have more electrical *potential* energy (of which voltage is a measure) than charges at the other. When an external path for charges to flow is present, the charges accelerate along that path, always towards a place of lower potential energy. By accelerating, potential energy is converted to kinetic energy. They donate that kinetic energy to whatever they encounter on the way, always arriving at the other source terminal with zero (relative) potential energy.

By contrast, for a current source, the charges start with *kinetic* energy (of which current is indirectly a measure). The source propels charges at a constant rate through itself. Assuming there's some path provided for those charges to leave, travel around, and return to the source, there will be some potential difference developed across that path in accordance with Ohm's law.

If you place a low resistance across the source, then very little energy will be required to "push" the charges along the path, at the rate prescribed by the source, and so the measured potential difference developed across the source will be low. The higher the resistance, the higher the developed potential difference. This is why it's bad (even dangerous) to use switches to interrupt current through an inductor. The inductor is a current source (charges being propelled by the collapsing magnetic field), and by suddenly raising the resistance of the path through which those charges travel, potential difference across the inductor necessarily rises, unconstrained.

By connecting a voltage source in parallel with a current source, you have one device setting the rules regarding potential energy that charges must start and end with, and another that is in control of the kinetic energy that those charges will possess on their travels. They are not in conflict. Whatever kinetic energy the current source insists upon is not opposed by the voltage source, and whatever initial/final potential energy levels the voltage source dictates, the current source has no problem with.

In this model, both voltage and current sources can be either providers of energy, or receivers, and which it is depends on current direction and voltage polarity. By [passive sign convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention), if voltage across something and and current through it have the same sign, the thing is *receiving* energy. For example, a resistor always meets this condition, and always *receives* energy, converting it to heat.

The sources, though, can have current and voltage of equal or opposite signs, meaning they can act as energy sources or energy sinks, providing or receiving energy. A cell, for example, which is a voltage source, is charging when both its current and voltage have the same sign, since it's receiving energy. Power \$P=IV\$ is positive when the signs of \$I\$ and \$V\$ are the same, indicating a device that's receiving energy.

The point I made before about simultaneous equations (in terms of current, voltage and resistance), where I suggested that there's no cause and effect, can be revisited, from an energy perspective.

In physics, there's always a tendency for a system to change towards a state of lower total energy. In that sense, there *is* a cause and an effect; the cause is having energy to lose, and the effect is to lose it. This is all encapsulated in the laws of thermodynamics.

Let me use an analogy. A ball rolls on a hill in a direction that causes it to lose potential energy, gain kinetic energy, and it donates that kinetic energy to whatever it encounters on the way, always ending up at the bottom of the hill with no energy at all.

Therefore, while I've never heard it stated this way, and I might get roasted for saying this: conditions such as voltage and current are always established in a configuration that causes the entire system to lose energy as fast as possible. All charges are rolling down potential gradients, in a direction where that gradient (slope) is greatest. The [lumped element model (LEM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumped-element_model), of which Ohm's law, KVL and KCL are members, is a simplification that hides this universal behaviour.

Behind the LEM curtain, though, it is energy that drives everything, under the laws governing it, the laws of thermodynamics. Unless there's some even deeper principle at work, energy is the driving cause for all effects, such as currents and voltages we find in a circuit. In this sense it is naive to think of voltage pushing current, or current developing voltage, even though these may be useful pedagogical tools. The truth is that all systems tend towards zero energy, and conditions always arrange themselves to do this as quickly as possible. It's a kind of magic.

Being ideal sources, the energy reserves are infinite, but the universe doesn't know this, setting up the usual conditions. In the real world, though, the energy sources will eventually be depleted, and all charges in the circuit will have no more potential energy than any other, with nothing to donate, and all kinetic energy will have been lost to the environment. Everything will stop, in a kind of localised circuit "heat death" that physicists like to talk about in the context of the whole universe.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of understanding simple circuits such as this one, is to realize that a circuit-diagram is not so much a representation of reality, as it is just a system of equations.

In your circuit, you have four variables:

- The voltage of the ground-node. Let's call this \$v_A\$.
- The voltage above the voltage source. Let's call this \$v_B\$.
- The voltage above the current source. Let's call this \$v_C\$.
- The current around the loop, which is the same for all components here. Let's just call this \$i\$, and define it to be positive in the counter-clockwise direction.

Each symbol introduces an equation between some of these variables:

1. The ground symbol introduces \$v_A = 0V\$
2. The voltage source introduces \$v_B - v_A = 4V\$
3. The current source introduces \$i = 2mA\$
4. The resistor, following Ohm's law, introduces \$v_C - v_B = 2kΩ \times i\$

Looking at these equations, we can quite quickly see that \$v_B = 4V\$ (from equations 1 and 2), and that \$v_C = 2kΩ \times 2mA + 4V = 8V\$.

This is just a more formal way of saying what other answers has said: A constant voltage source will *by definition* always have the specified voltage across it, and a current source will *by definition* have the specified current running through it. Drawing two voltage sources with different voltage in parallel is the same as writing the equation \$1 = 2\$. It simply doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I have to think about it more formally. It should be taken as axiom that when current source is present, then current always flows in direction stated, while with voltage source +/- does not always mean that + has higher potential energy. Majority of circuit elements have equations which are not too far off from physics concepts, but current source looks like very obscure object further away from immediate physics interpretation.

Comment: Exactly. All circuit elements have equations, although you generally need differential equations to do anything that is not steady-state. A circuit diagram is simply a graphical way of assembling these equations into one big system of equations that may, or may not, have any solutions. (And you are correct, that a current source is an unusually idealized component, since real-world counterparts are not as common as, say, a resistor.)

Answer (score 1):

## Basic idea

Understanding circuits begins with building an intuitive idea of electrical sources in their two extreme varieties - *constant voltage source* and *constant current source*.

### Static notion

However, the classic 19th century view of them as *static devices* that somehow by themselves produce constant (load-independent) voltage and current only works for formal analysis and superficial "understanding".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvQho1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr0ctY.png)</sup>

### Dynamic notion

The modern understanding of electrical sources requires us to imagine them as *dynamic devices* (regulators) that do something to maintain their quantity. Figuratively speaking, we think of them as living "beings" that respond to any attempts to change the quantities they support.

## Implementation

### Unloaded sources

To understand what sources are, we have to symbolically "open" these "circles" and see what is inside.

In the simplest implementation, both sources contain the same thing - an *"internal" voltage source* and a *variable resistor* in series (when there is more than one source in a circuit, it is accepted that there is only one common power source and the role of the local "sources" is performed by the dynamic resistances). They differ only in the way they (we) change the resistance.

**Voltage source:** There is no load current, so there is no voltage drop across Ri, and the output voltage is equal to the internal voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFV5um.png)</sup>

**Current source:** There is no load resistance (short circuit), so the current is determined only by Vi and Ri.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsCO7O.png)</sup>

In electronic circuits, transistors, op-amps, and other active devices do this job, but for the purposes of our intuitive understanding, we can do it ourselves putting yourself in their place. The benefit of this is that we will understand what and how they do it, and this will help us later in understanding circuits with these devices.

### Loaded sources

**Voltage source:** Imagine that a voltage source with 10 V internal voltage and 100 Ω resistance creates 8 V across a 400 Ω load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiTTDf.png)</sup>

It increases its resistance Rv when the load current IL tries to decrease, and v.v., it decreases Rv when IL tries to increase so that to keep a constant voltage. For example, if the load RL increases its resistance to 600 Ω, the voltage source increases its resistance to 150 Ω, and the voltage remains 8 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f36Y0i.png)</sup>

Conversely, if the load decreases its resistance to 200 Ω, the voltage source decreases its resistance to 50 Ω, and again the voltage remains 8 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcP9nz.png)</sup>

You can think of the two resistances Rin and RL as a *dynamic voltage divider* that keeps its transfer ratio RL/(Rv + RL) constant.

**Current source:** Imagine that a current source with 10 V internal voltage and 8 kΩ resistance creates 1 mA through a 2 kΩ load. You can think of the two resistances in series as a network with a constant total resistance Ri + RL = 8 + 2 = 10 kΩ.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIXtmS.png)</sup>

***Dynamic resistor:*** The current source can decrease its resistance Ri when the load current IL tries to decrease, and v.v., it increases Ri when IL tries to increase so that to keep a constant current. For example, if the load RL increases its resistance to 3 kΩ, the current source will decrease its resistance to 7 kΩ, and the current remains 1 mA since Ri + RL = 7 + 3 = 10 kΩ.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHcN8Z.png)</sup>

Conversely, the current source increases its resistance Ri when the load current IL tries to increase, and v.v., it decreases Ri when IL tries to decrease so that to keep a constant current. For example, if the load RL decreases its resistance to 1 kΩ, the current source will increase its resistance to 9 kΩ, and the current remains 1 mA since Ri + RL = 9 + 1 = 10 kΩ.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdeBme.png)</sup>

***Dynamic voltage source:*** With the same success, a current source can change its internal voltage Vi (up to infinity, in the case of "ideal" current source) instead resistance. So, when the load current IL tries to decrease (the load resistance RL tries to increase to 3 kΩ), Vi  increases to 11 V so that to restore the 1 mA current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzoH2V.png)</sup>

Conversely, when the load current IL tries to increase since the load resistance RL decreases to 1 kΩ, Vi decreases to 9 V so that to restore the 1 mA current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZfwhu.png)</sup>

However, this *dynamic voltage* implementation is not as popular in electronic circuits as *dynamic resistance* one, where we prefer to work with relatively low fixed voltages.

## Interacting sources

When we connect two or more sources in the same circuit, they begin to interact because each of them tries to maintain its quantity.

### Opposing sources

When they are the same (maintain the same kind of quantity), they begin to "fight"; thus a kind of "tag of war" is obtained.

**Voltage sources:** If two voltage sources with (slightly) different voltages are connected in parallel, they will change their internal resistances in opposite directions thus trying to keep their voltages. As a result, the current between them will enormously change. Differential ("long-tailed") pair is an example of this configuration. Let's consider the three typical cases.

**V1 = V2:** There is no conflict between the two voltage sources since they create the same voltage across the 200 Ω load (ammeter with the same internal resistance).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6hDrb.png)</sup>

**V1 > V2:** V1 tries to increase the common voltage by decreasing its internal resistance and V2 opposes it by increasing its resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiDYXD.png)</sup>

**V1 < V2:** V1 tries to decrease the common voltage by increasing its internal resistance and V2 opposes it by decreasing its resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgL9Lr.png)</sup>

**Current sources:** If two current sources with (slightly) different currents are connected in series, they will change their internal resistances in opposite directions thus trying to keep their currents. As a result, the  midpoint voltage will change enormously. Transistor amplifier stages with *dynamic load* are example of this configuration. Let's consider the three typical cases.

**I1 = I2:** There is no conflict between the two current sources since they produce the same current; Ri1 + Ri2 = 10 + 10 = 20 kΩ.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWJW4A.png)</sup>

**I1 > I2:** I1 tries to increase the common current by decreasing its internal resistance and I2 opposes it by increasing its resistance; Ri1 + Ri2 = 5 + 15 = 20 kΩ.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffVcTC.png)</sup>

**I1 < I2:** I1 tries to decrease the common current by increasing its internal resistance and I2 opposes it by decreasing its resistance; Ri1 + Ri2 = 15 + 5 = 20 kΩ.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgYHSx.png)</sup>

### Helping sources

When the sources are different (maintain different kinds of quantity), they begin to "help" each other. Imagine that a voltage source V producing 0 V voltage is connected to a current source I producing 1 mA current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCdCoL.png)</sup>

**Voltage source helps current source:** When the current source "decides" to change (e.g., increase) the common current to 2 mA, it begins changing its internal resistance in the corresponding direction (decreases it to 5 kΩ). Trying to keep its voltage unchanged, the voltage source changes its resistance in the same direction (decreases it to 5 kΩ); thus it "helps" the current source. A varying emitter biasing of the differential pair and cascode circuits are examples of this circuit phenomenon.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS3tcC.png)</sup>

**Current source helps voltage source:** When the voltage source "decides" to change the voltage (e.g., increases it to 5 V), it begins changing its internal resistance in the corresponding direction (decreases it to 5 kΩ). Trying to keep its current unchanged, the current source changes its resistance in the opposite direction (increases it to 15 kΩ); thus it "helps" the voltage source. An emitter biasing of the differential pair in common mode is an example of this circuit phenomenon.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEwpuO.png)</sup>